# My appium test is running twice one one device but I need to run it across two devices in paralell

Tags: java, selenium, appium, selenium-grid

I am trying to run my appium tests in paralell. I have configured selenium grid and registered my nodes via an appium command. I have two test devices (emulators) running and whenever I try to run a test it launches the app on both devices but runs the test twice on one of the devices. This is my `@BeforeMethod` code:

```
    @BeforeMethod
    @Parameters({"deviceName", "platformVersion"})
    public void beforeTest(String deviceName, String platformVersion) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        prop = new GeneralProperties();


            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", platformVersion);
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", prop.getPlatformName());
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", deviceName);
            capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", prop.getAppPackage());
            capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", prop.getAppActivity());
            capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "uiautomator2");
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);

            driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(prop.getUrl()), capabilities);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(prop.getImplicitWait(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        } else if (deviceName.equals("emulator-5556")) {

            // read data from properties file and set capabilities
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", platformVersion);
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", prop.getPlatformName());
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", deviceName);
            capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", prop.getAppPackage());
            capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", prop.getAppActivity());
            capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "uiautomator2");
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);

            driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(prop.getUrl()), capabilities);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(prop.getImplicitWait(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        }
        drivers.set(driver);
}
```

This is my `testng.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<test name="Emulator">
    <parameter name="deviceName" value="emulator-5554"/>
    <parameter name="platformVersion" value="10"/>

    <classes>
        <class name="com.test.Login.VerifyValidLogin_Regression"></class>
    </classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
<test name="Emulator_2">
    <parameter name="deviceName" value="emulator-5556"/>
    <parameter name="platformVersion" value="9"/>

    <classes>
        <class name="com.test.Login.VerifyValidLogin_Regression"></class>
    </classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
```

I'm not getting any error but I have been struggling with this for some time now

Answer (score 1):

you're real close. You are just missing the suite tags, since you are running tests in parallel you are running a suite so it should look like this

```
<suite name="suitename" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Emulator">
        <parameter name="deviceName" value="emulator-5554"/>
        <parameter name="platformVersion" value="10"/>

        <classes>
            <class name="com.test.Login.VerifyValidLogin_Regression"></class>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
    <test name="Emulator_2">
        <parameter name="deviceName" value="emulator-5556"/>
        <parameter name="platformVersion" value="9"/>

        <classes>
            <class name="com.test.Login.VerifyValidLogin_Regression"> . </class>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite>
```

the thread-count will be the number of devices you are running on at once in your case 2 but if you have more of less devices just change the thread count